# Mac hardware cursor overlapping custom cursor unity c#

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

The game I am developing has a custom cursor. As a result of the cursor size, I have to use Cursor.SetCursor with CursorMode set to ForceSoftware (having CursorMode set to Auto squashes the cursor and doesn't look good at all). This works fine on windows, however on mac, the default mac cursor overlaps the software cursor, which as you can imagine doesn't look right. I have looked all over for a way to fix this, but I haven't had any luck. I have tried just setting the cursor in unity's player settings, but that distorts the cursor texture. At the moment it is just this line of code that sets the cursor

```
private void Start(){
    Cursor.SetCursor(cursor, new Vector2(-1, 1), CursorMode.ForceSoftware);
}
```

Where cursor is a Texture2D that I assign in the unity editor. I know this is probably a very simple problem to fix, but I really am not sure how to go about fixing it for mac systems.

Answer (score 3):

> The default mac cursor overlaps the software cursor

The problem lies within your [`Cursor.SetCursor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor.SetCursor.html) code, because you are forcing the cursor to be a software cursor instead of the hardware cursor it needs to be.

Because some plattforms support only one hardware cursor and cursors created at runtime via. [`Cursor.SetCursor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor.SetCursor.html) are seen as software cursors and don't "*replace*" the hardware cursor.

**Example:**

```cs
Cursor.SetCursor(cursorTexture, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
```

The most important setting to make it work with Mac or other platforms that support only one hardware cursor is setting `CursorMode.Auto`. So it actually *"replaces"* the hardware cursor.

Comment: Ah okay I see, thank you, this is a method I tried originally, but it did the same thing as just setting the cursor as the default one in the project settings, i.e. it squashed the cursor to try and force it to be 32x32 size. Which is too small for the cursor we have and just looks strange. Thank you for the assistance though, if we can't figure out any other way to get the cursor to display across all platforms with the appropriate size I shall utilize this method. Thanks :)

Comment: Problem is the cursor won't work after alt-tab once